# Measuring running time of CUDA program

Tags: profiling, cuda

I use the Linux program `time` to measure the running time of my CUDA program, and it shows up something like this:

```
real        0m10.269s
user        0m6.520s
sys         0m5.336s
```

My question is: Is the GPU execution time included in the `sys` part or the `user` part?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't tell - it could even be neither of them.

To time CUDA tasks you need to use the performance timers built into CUDA, see the [best practices guide](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/4_0_rc2/toolkit/docs/CUDA_C_Best_Practices_Guide.pdf)

Comment: Thank you, but this is quite sad :( .